# Got Powerful Virus On Company laptop. What now?

Tags: malware

I have no idea what to do. I got a virus somehow and this is what I found out and tried so far.

cmd opens and close alone
if I type anything related to spyware or malware in browers it closes it. all of them
I got porn ads if I don't use adblock.
it blocks me malwares if I'm not on safe mode.

Clean cookies
Run MalwareBytes, it doesn't run even on safe mode.
Run SpyBot, didn't help

What can I do? I cannot format my computer.

Any help?

Comment: Get some antivirus software eg: [Avira](https://www.avira.com/de/index) or [AVG](https://www.avg.com)

Answer (score 0):

If your PC is absolutely F'd, then your only option may to use a windows boot disc and attempt to remove the virus or do system recovery.

Firstly I recommend disconnecting from any wifi or web-source before attempting repairs. When you enter your boot recovery options, you can open a CMD window and type `wmic LOGICALDISK LIST BRIEF`. This command will display your avalible drives you can `CD` to.

From there you open a `.txt` document and click `save as`. This will allow you to explore your files. I recommend to firstly check if there is any `system restore` point made you can recover from. If alls lost, you might have to do a system format. Windows 8+ allows to simply reinstall the base windows files instead of wiping it completely.